# Are there any good (functional) neural network simulators for Windows?

Tags: windows, neural-network

I've tried using SNNS but only on a Linux machine, and it's fairly awful. Since my home machine is Windows 7, I was hoping there'd be a decent neural network simulator for Windows. SNNS does have a Java version, but it's equally as if not more awful to use.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want a free solution, there's [Emergent](http://grey.colorado.edu/emergent/index.php/Main_Page) and [Neural Lab](http://www.dicis.ugto.mx/profesores/sledesma/documentos/index.htm). Emergent has a better community, plus Neural Lab is still being developed.
There are paid programs too, but I figure an edu sim should work just as well (it probably has a worse interface is all).

Answer (score 2):

The Fast Artificial Neural Network library (FANN) is a free open source neural network library, which implements multilayer artificial neural networks in C and supports both fully and sparsely connected networks.
FANNTool is a GUI to the FANN library which allows its easy usage without the need o programming

http://code.google.com/p/fanntool/

Comment: Please don't leave uncommented links on this site. If needs be, copy some text from the site or write a short paragraph describing why you're leaving the link here, and what it points to. The best, when the content on that page is really short (and it is legal to copy it), make a copy of the content and post here instead. If the page with that content goes away in the future, your answer is at that point void and unhelpful. The very best answer would of course be if you re-worded the content on that page in your own words, and then just provided a source link for verification.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know ANYTHING about this topic, but maybe this comparison chart will help?

[Neural Network Simulators](http://grey.colorado.edu/emergent/index.php/Comparison_of_Neural_Network_Simulators)